# PHP file not executing in Ubuntu command line

Tags: php, ubuntu, command-line, cron

I am trying to execute a script via the command line of SSH and i have had no luck so far, I have tried the following

```
php -f /var/www/example.com/cron/external_resource.php
php /var/www/example.com/cron/external_resource.php
```

None of these I've had any luck with. Works fine in the web browser and adds to the database. Does nothing by running in the command.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: What does that file do? Could you share its code? If the code depends on some web server based conditions, i.e. check and insert data from `$_POST`, etc. it would be absolutely normal that nothing gets insered in the DB, since the script is running in `cli` mode.

Comment: It has no POST or GET. It requires zero input and when i load the url in the browser it does what i need it to. It does have a PHP include, could this be a problem?

Comment: It depends on how you're including the file, that is if you're building the path to the included file, how do you do this.
On a side note, are you sure that `php-cli` is installed and active on that machine? What is the output of `php --version` when you run it from the console?

Comment: Hi Havelock, php version returns: PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.14 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep  4 2014 07:14:16) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

Comment: the include is as follows: include_once '../myinclude.inc';